# [Drools]Fact Objects Mistakenly Updated During Multi-Stage Rule Firing OR wtih Long Fact Object List

Tags: drools

If the subject is confusing, that is because the problem itself is way too confusing to us. Here is the thing.

We have an application that leverages Drools' rule engine to help us evaluate java beans - Fact Objects in Drool's term - on their field values and update a particular flag field within the bean to "true" or "false" according to the evaluation result. All the evaluations and update operations are defined in the template.

The way it invokes Drools is like this. First it creates a stateful session before the first use. And when we have a list of beans, we insert them one by one to the session, and call fireAllRules. After firing the rules, we keep the session for later uses. And once we have another batch of beans, we do the same again, and again, and again...

This sounds making sense. But later during the testing, we found that although during the first batch, the rule engine worked fine, the following batches didn't. Some beans were mistakenly updated, that is, even no fields did match any rules, the flag was updated to true.

Then we thought maybe we should not reuse the session. So we put all beans from all batches into one big list. But soon we found that the problematic beans still got wrong update. And what's more weird, if we run this testing on different machines, problematic bean could be different. But if we test any of the problematic beans in unit test with itself, everything works fine.

Now I hope I have explained the problem. We are new to Drools. Maybe we did something wrong somewhere that we don't know. Could anyone here give any direction of the problem? That'll us a very big favor!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me as though you're not clearing out working memory after each 'fireAllRules'.

If you use a stateful session, then every fact which you insert will remain in working memory until you explicitly retract it. Therefore every time you fire rules, you are re-evaluating the original set of facts, plus the new ones.

It might be useful to add a little debugging to your code. Using session.getObjects(), you will be able to see what facts are in working memory before and after execution of the rules. This should indicate what is not being retracted between evaluations.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the pointing! I was about to lose hope of anyone could help. Actually we were suspecting about the same thing but we couldn't find the right way to clear the working memory. We tried to use the "retract" method, but although the FactObject count reduced, same issue still happened. Then we decided to put all objects into one big list and fire the rules for once. Unfortunately  we got the same problematic result. But anyway, I think it's a great idea to check the session.getObjects() as you suggested. We shall try it the first thing today. Thanks for your help.